# runtime initialization a const

Tags: c++, constants, extern

I have a header (only) file constants.h, where I define all the constant variables, to be used later in the library. However, there is one variable, which I would like to define run-time in an implementation file. I tried to do something like this:

constant.hpp

```
    extern const unsigned int numTests;
```

somewhere else in run.cpp

```
    const unsigned int numTests = 10;
```

and, then yet another file tester.cpp uses

```
    if ( n < numTests) {
       // do something
    }
```

Now, when I compile it, I get a linker error in tester.o as undefined symbol numTests. I sort of understand why this is happening: the tester.cpp includes constants.hpp and not the run.cpp and so, it can not find the constant numTests initialized in run.cpp.

Is there any better way to do it?

TIA,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are compiling both `run.cpp` and `tester.cpp` when you compile your program and you won't get a linker error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link run.o when creating the executable:

```
g++ -o tester tester.cpp run.o   ; for GNU C++
```

(Check your own compiler's command line switches if you're not using GNU C++)